# Webpack interprets imported css as jsx when loading in a bundle

Tags: reactjs, webpack

main.jsx

```
import React              from 'react';
import ReactDOM           from 'react-dom';

const src = require('../images/av.png');
require('../css/styles.css');

class APP extends React.Component{


    render(){
      //Render main component
      return (
        <div >
              Hello!
               <img src={src} /> 
        </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  //React routing
  (<APP />),
  document.getElementById('app'));
```

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: {
    javascript: './static/jsx/main.jsx'
  },
  output: {
      path: path.resolve('./static/js/app/'),
      filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
  module: {    
    preLoaders: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: 'source-map'
        }
    ],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/, 
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader" 
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=25000',
      }
    ]
  },
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "license": "",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "gulp": "gulp",
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "start-webpack-server": "webpack-dev-server --hot --inline --colors --progress"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-cli": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.6.5",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.15.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.0.16",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.11.0",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "es6-promise": "^4.0.5",
    "eslint": "^3.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.6.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-babel": "^6.1.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-html-replace": "^1.6.1",
    "gulp-react": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2",
    "webpack-stream": "^3.2.0",
  "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5"
  }
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to load image and css files into my jsx . I had problems with images but now they get loaded fine. Anyway css files are interpreted as jsx by webpack although I set the css-loader for it. When I run transpiling for the project I get this error:

```
ERROR in ./static/css/styles.css
Module parse failed: D:\work\simpleLeafLet\static\css\styles.css Unexpected token (2:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (2:0)
```

Comment: Maybe it's nothing, but I think you have a typo in your first loader in `test: /.jsx?$/`, you're missing the `\` before the `.`. You have it right in the `preLoaders`

Comment: @MatthewHerbst you are right. It turned up to be the reason. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is a simple typo

```
...
loaders: [
      {

        test: /.jsx?$/,

        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react']
        }
      },
...
```

It should be

```
...
loaders: [
      {

        test: /\.jsx?$/,

        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react']
        }
      },
...
```

I missed \ in "test: /\.jsx?$/"